# React component hide OR re-create?

Tags: performance, dom, reactjs

I am building a reactjs application, I have two options for rendering the components

1. One is hiding the component and appending the other component on top
   of it with the same space and different layout.
2. The other option is re-render and re-create DOM for both the components
   separately.

React uses diff algorithm to compare and change the states of the DOM, as the component is already present in the DOM so the first solution may work faster. But it will have more amount of in-memory data than the second solution.

On the other hand in the second solution, we have to remove the DOM of one component, render the other component and create the DOM for it again. That looks like a lot of work!

I am confused, which approach should I follow?

This can be depicted as:

```
<Component1/>
<Component2/>
```

Solution 1: `Hide <Component1/> and Append <Component2/> in the same space.`

Solution 2: `Remove <Componen1/> and Append <Component2/> in the same space`

Comment: are the components different? is component 2 the same as component 1 with different content?

Comment: You should measure and compare results. In the end, there is high possibility you will trigger layout/repaint on browser - no matter which option you end up with.

Comment: They are different with different content!

Comment: @Andreyco, Anyways repainting is gonna happen in both the cases. The question is which solution will be more optimized.

Comment: I would go for rendering only when necessary (e.g. remove from DOM when not needed/visible). Let React handle this.

Answer (score 1):

You are prematurely optimizing.  You've probably already spent more engineering time on this problem than it is worth.  Option 2 is simpler to implement, simpler to reason about, and is the happy path when working with React.

If, after you've built it, you feel it is performing too slowly, then you should do some performance profiling and find the bottlenecks.  Don't worry about Option 1 until, and only if, this profiling suggests that the recreation of the DOM elements is the bottleneck.

Comment: If it clears my concepts better in react then I would say it's the time well spent!